# Representation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k)^{1/n}}{n^k}$ in terms of Riemann zeta function for fixed integer k >1?

Tags: convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta, upper-lower-bounds

I tried many times to write this$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k)^{1/n}}{n^k}$ in terms of Riemann zeta function but all my attempts are failed, however I [conjuctred](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28+3%5E%281%2Fn%29%2Fn%5E3%29%2C+n%3D1+to+infty+)  that the integer part of this sum equal to $k$ or we may can write  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(k)^{1/n}}{n^k}\geq k, k>1$ , Now my question here is : Is it possible to represent that sum in terms of Riemann zeta function ?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  The first term of the sum is $\frac k1=k$, yes?  So, isn't the sum trivially greater than $k$?

Comment: sorry , I have a wrong typo , I meant greater thank not less , thanks for ur attention

Comment: As I say, since the first term is $k$, it is obvious that the sum is $>k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience write $b = \ln(k)$.  You can write
$$ k^{1/n} = \exp(b/n) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty b^j n^{-j}/j!$$
so your sum is
$$ \eqalign{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{b^j} {n^{j+k} j!} &= 
\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b^j} {n^{j+k} j!}\cr
&= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{b^j}{j!} \zeta(j+k)} $$

Comment: Nice and slick answer